# add a <link rel="canonical" dynamically in the head tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I need to add link rel tags to the head tag dynamically based on what page is being loaded. Is there a way to do this using the page.header.controls.add method? or is it only possible through javascript or jquery? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: would probably be best to do this server side with whatever CGI programming language you prefer.  In this case you'll use ASP.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i am a newbie, could you please elaborate? much appreciated

Comment: I say it is best to use server side for this because if a request is made by a user you want the server to process the output before the user gets it.  This would make more sense to do in a server language in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) class for this:-

```
HtmlGenericControl linkFile = new HtmlGenericControl("link");
linkFile.Attributes.Add("rel", "canonical");
linkFile.Attributes.Add("href", "testPath");
Page.Header.Controls.Add(linkFile);
```

Comment: thanks, tried this earlier too but cant see the link tag in the page source, am i missing something here?

Comment: i added this in the code behind for the master page, am i doing it wrong?

Comment: @Mani - I mean in which event? Add it in `Page_Load` event of master page.

Comment: Weird! How you are validating its added or not? Check the page source.

Comment: Checked the page source - used this too    HtmlLink clink = new HtmlLink();
                    clink.Attributes.Add(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Rel.ToString().ToLower(), "canonical");
                    clink.Href = "http://www.test.com/";
                    Page.Header.Controls.Add(clink); doesnt work!

Comment: @Mani - I am not sure what you are doing wrong, the code which I have posted is working fine for me, can you please show how you are adding this code?

Comment: seems that i have found out what was wrong with what I was doing, this should work, thank you very much Rahul :)

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this

`if(!document.getElementById('id2')) {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.id = 'id2';
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = 'CSS/Css1.cs';
    document.head.appendChild(link);
}`

Comment: The code above does not add a link rel="canonical" - I suggest you test with that scenario, just in case the behavior is different.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use this:

```
 HtmlLink clink = new HtmlLink();
    clink.Attributes.Add( HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Rel.ToString().ToLower(), "canonical");
    clink.Href = "http://www.test.co.in/";
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(clink);
```